# System.String does not implement the interface System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, .net

I occasionally find that the class `System.String` of the .NET framework does not implement its inherited interface `System.IConvertible`, why, please?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

What you're witnessing is something called "explicit interface implementation".  What this means is that if you define a class (in this case `System.String`) and implement an interface (in this case `System.IConvertible`) and you implement it using explicit interface syntax, i.e.

This:

```
bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToBoolean(this, provider);
}
```

Vs.

```
public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToBoolean(this, provider);
}
```

Then the method `ToBoolean` will not be accessible if the compile-time-type of the target of the method is actually an instance of your type, rather than the interface.  This is really a way for API writers in C# to "hide" certain members that, though for various reasons must be implemented by the implementing type, are not really intended to be part of the public surface area of your type.  It's actually pretty nice, as it allows you to make your API cleaner than it might otherwise have been.

In this case, the reason one might consider it cleaner to prevent consumers from interacting with `string` as a simple `IConverter` is that the whole *point* of `System.Convert` is to allow converting values of types such as `string` into types such as `bool` by *using* these methods.  Therefore, providing the interface-methods as a way to do the same thing that `System.Convert` already does would only confuse the API by providing uselessly additional ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

`System.String` implement the interface `IConvertible` explicitly. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) for reference.

So the methods are only "visible", when you assign a string to a variable of type `IConvertible`.

```
string mystring = "Hello World";

IConvertible convertible = mystring as IConvertible.
```